# XSS on img tag onerror

Tags: javascript, xss

I am testing a website and i fount that in an img when the src is not found the onerror uses another image. if i inspect and change the onerror with an alert it fully works. Is this potential XSS vulnerability?

Comment: If the `onerror` content can come from an untrusted source (like user input, being rendered to other users), yes, it's a problem

Answer (score 3):

The ability of a user to edit the DOM in their own browser is not an XSS vulnerability (although it might be a vector for a phishing attack).

`onerror`, like *any* attribute with a value that is treated as JavaScript, can be used as part of an XSS attack if the attacker can inject content into it (or create the attribute as part of injecting content into an HTML document).